# Numeric keyboard is not showing

Tags: android

Hı Guys.I have a quesiton about linear layout.I have a linear layout that contains some textviews.What i want to do that when i click the linear layout,to open numeric keyboard. I have tried many ways but they does not working for linear.Do you have any idea?

Comment: Fo what purpose do you need keyboard? If you have only textviews you wouldn't need it

Comment: use edittext.... with number input type

Comment: if the  keyboard opens,i will get number that the user enters and will write it textviews.

Comment: when you have entered the number you can save it in textview

Answer (score 1):

Use `EditText` for input.  Set `android:inputType="number"` to indicate that the keyboard should allow only numeric input.

Resources:

- https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html
- https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style.html
- https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: I have to write them to textviews in the linear layout.I can use Edittext but this time I have to use textview